# Issue with jquery Hide() function on a dynamically added DIV

Tags: html, css

I have a table and when i mouseover a particular column of the table i get the tooltip. BUt when i move the mouse pointer to another area the tooltip still stays even though i have written code to hide the tooltip. Below is the code. 
What am I doing wrong? I dont use any plugins. Plan to use but want to try once before resorting to the plugins.

```
<script>
            $(function () {
                $(".content-cardnumber").mouseover(function (event) {
                    createToolTip(event);
                }).mouseout(function () {
                    $("#popup").hide();
                });
            });
            function createToolTip(event){
                $('<div class="tooltip" id="popup">Cardnumber<div>').appendTo('body');
                var tPosX = event.pageX - 10;
                var tPosY = event.pageY - 10;
                $('div.tooltip').css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'top': tPosY, 'left': tPosX });
            }
        </script>
```

This is how the html looks like.

```
<tr>
                    <th class="content-cardnumber">Card Number</th>
                    <th class="content-eventcode">Event Code</th>
                    <th class="content-origintime">Event Time</th>            
                </tr>

                @foreach (IEvent e in Model.EventList)
                {
                    <tr class="events-row">
                        <td title="Test" class="content-cardnumber">@e.CardNumber</td>
                        <td class="content-eventcode">@e.EventCode</td>
                        <td class="content-origintime">@e.EventOriginTime</td>

                    </tr>
                }
```

Comment: first things first, see if that event is getting fired, add a `console.log('mouseout');` to the line above `$("#popup").hide();` and see if you have that written in your browsers console! - And, are you using any plugin, Bootstrap [Popup](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers) (or even [Tooltip](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips)) is really great and you don't even need javascript to fire the events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `createToolTip` function is **creating** a new `div` and appending it to the `body` on each `mouseover` event, but on `mouseout` you are not **removing** the div from the DOM but simply **hiding** it. so you end up with many tooltip divs (all with the same `id`) and that's why your `hide` doesn't work.

Also, you're having a typo in `$('<div class="tooltip" id="popup">Cardnumber<div>')`, should be `$('<div class="tooltip" id="popup">Cardnumber</div>')`.

Try:

```
$(function () {
                $(".content-cardnumber").mouseover(function (event) {
                    showToolTip(event);
                }).mouseout(function () {
                    $("#popup").hide();
                });
            });
            function showToolTip(event){
                if ($('#popup').length == 0)
                     $('<div class="tooltip" id="popup">Cardnumber</div>').appendTo('body');
                var tPosX = event.pageX - 10;
                var tPosY = event.pageY - 10;
                $('div.tooltip').css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'top': tPosY, 'left': tPosX }).show();
            }
```

Comment: When i tried this the tooltip came only the very first time but it did go away when i changed focus. :(

Comment: I revised my answer. added `show()` after setting `css()` of the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead of `mouseover`, `mouseout`.

`mouseover` event handler is called if you move cursor inside `.content-cardnumber` element. that will create many `div`s.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating more than one tooltip with the id "popup"?
Check your generated source because that would break it (I think)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: when you document is ready the div popup doesnt exist

```
 <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".content-cardnumber").mouseenter(function (event) {
                createToolTip(event);
            }).mouseleave(function () {
               hideTooltip();///try this
            });
        });
        function createToolTip(event){
            $('<div class="tooltip" id="popup">Cardnumber<div>').appendTo('body');
            var tPosX = event.pageX - 10;
            var tPosY = event.pageY - 10;
            $('div.tooltip').css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'top': tPosY, 'left': tPosX });
        }

 function hideTooltip(){
  $("#popup").remove();
 }
</script>
```